# How do I get the row with maximum value after doing a groupby on the table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have been dealing with this problem for a while.
I am doing a `groupby` on the interval `[0..6]` and `stop_names`. I am trying to get the interval and `stop_name` that has the maximal mean value.

So far I am doing this, for each `stop_name` I would like to get the mean delay:

```
delays_with_stop_names.groupby(['interval','stop_name'])['delay'].mean()
```

And I get this:

```
interval  stop_name        
0         ABBAYE               4901.848837
          ACACIAS              2671.000000
          AERODROME            3639.608696
...

6         YSER                 -851.256949
          ZAMAN-FOREST NAT.     -42.568000
          ZAVELPUT               28.512195
```

Now my goal is from this to get the stop for each interval that has the max value. It would look like this:

```
0 ABBAYE 4901
1 AAAAAA 123123
2 BBBBBB 2222
...
6 ZAVELPUT 28
```

I tried doing double `groupby`'s but it did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `rank` method as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)

example

### Creating example DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
('0','ABBAYE', 4901.848837,),
('0','ACACIAS', 2671.000000,),
('0','AERODROME', 3639.608696,),
('6','YSER',-851.256949,),
('6','ZAMAN-FOREST NAT.',-42.568000,),
('6','ZAVELPUT', 28.512195,),
]

columns_names = [
    'interval',
    'stop_name',
    'delay',
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns_names)
df.to_markdown()
```

|  | interval | stop_name | delay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | ABBAYE | 4901.85 |
| 1 | 0 | ACACIAS | 2671 |
| 2 | 0 | AERODROME | 3639.61 |
| 3 | 6 | YSER | -851.257 |
| 4 | 6 | ZAMAN-FOREST NAT. | -42.568 |
| 5 | 6 | ZAVELPUT | 28.5122 |

### Adding Rank Column

Notice that, as you want the higher value, you will need to use `ascending=False`

```py
df['rank_by_delay'] = df.groupby('interval')['delay'].rank(method='first', ascending=False)
df.to_markdown()
```

|  | interval | stop_name | delay | rank_by_delay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | ABBAYE | 4901.85 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | ACACIAS | 2671 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | AERODROME | 3639.61 | 2 |
| 3 | 6 | YSER | -851.257 | 3 |
| 4 | 6 | ZAMAN-FOREST NAT. | -42.568 | 2 |
| 5 | 6 | ZAVELPUT | 28.5122 | 1 |

### Filtering the appropriate rows

Now you can simply filter using the new column

```py
df[df['rank_by_delay'] == 1]
```

|  | interval | stop_name | delay | rank_by_delay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | ABBAYE | 4901.85 | 1 |
| 5 | 6 | ZAVELPUT | 28.5122 | 1 |